# Not Getting results after running python statements in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am very new to python. Trying to execute following code in Jupyter Notebook. Not getting any response or error. Please help.

```
from datetime import date
from nsepy import get_history
sbin = get_history(symbol='SBIN',
               start=date(2015,1,1),
               end=date(2015,1,10))
```

Comment: You are not printing any of the information out. Use `print(sbin)` beneath the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are assigning the variable you will need to call it again below that to have it show up.

```
from datetime import date
from nsepy import get_history
sbin = get_history(symbol='SBIN',
           start=date(2015,1,1),
           end=date(2015,1,10))
sbin
```

Comment: additionally, jupyter will only show the bottom variable called. If you want more you'll need to use print()